# About pyjamas maturity vs GWT maturity (with short dead lines) for a web application

Tags: java, python, gwt, pyjamas

I love both, python and Java and I have this first '*serious*' web application project that I would like to carry out.

I find it hard to choose between **pyjamas** + **django** and **GWT** + **Hibernate**.

In fact, from my beginner point of view, it seems like the python world is more suitable for a quickly-developed and fun web application. 
And, on the other hand, the java world is useful for performance-oriented, scalable solutions and for 'serious' projects with big money involved...

My requirements are quite simple: this application has to replace a desktop application. So, the performance factor is there. But my deadlines are pretty short.

Is **pyjamas** mature enough to replace **GWT** on a performance and functionality point of view?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> In fact, from my beginner point of
>   view, it seems like the python world
>   is more suitable for a
>   quickly-developed and fun web
>   application. And, on the other hand,
>   the java world is useful for
>   performance-oriented, scalable
>   solutions and for 'serious' projects
>   with big money involved...

Naah.  For example, YouTube is in Python -- where do you see that affecting its performance, scalability, or "big money" characteristics?

> Is pyjamas mature enough to replace
>   GWT on a performance and functionality
>   point of view?

Completely different question from the previous, silly observation.

GWT has been around for longer, and has more users and contributors.  Perhaps pyjamas is "good enough" for many uses -- nevertheless, it **is** at release 0.7, with GWT at release 2.0, which can be taken as an indication that GWT is better, more developed and mature.

Most real-world, highly-scalable web apps use "real" Javascript (typically with some supporting framework, such as the very popular jQuery or any of its many "competitors"); if, for whatever reason, you can't (or, more likely, don't want to), then GWT is probably a less risky choice than pyjamas, in my opinion.

Answer (score 4):

I've managed to deploy a couple of medium sized webapps using pyjamas and believe me, it was very smooth sailing. It's a slimmed-down version of GWT too so it is easier to learn. Most of the UI widgets are 100 lines ish! Also the pythonic use of OO is pretty exemplary.

Comment: Can you as well provide info on how easy it is to debug a pyjama application in comparison to GWT (pyjama does not have a hosted mode)?